# lambda expression for exists within list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

If I want to filter a list of objects against a specific id, I can do this:

```
list.Where(r => r.Id == idToCompare);
```

What if, instead of a single `idToCompare`, I have a list of Ids to compare against?

What is the syntax for comparing against a predefined list?  Something like:

```
int[] listofIds = GetListofIds();

list.Where(r => r.Id "in listofIds");
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If `listOfIds` is a list, this will work, but, List.Contains() is a linear search, so this isn't terribly efficient.

You're better off storing the ids you want to look up into a container that is suited for searching, like Set.

```
List<int> listOfIds = new List(GetListOfIds());
lists.Where(r=>listOfIds.Contains(r.Id));
```

Answer (score 26):

```
var query = list.Where(r => listofIds.Any(id => id == r.Id));
```

Another approach, useful if the listOfIds array is large:

```
HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>(listofIds);
var query = list.Where(r => hash.Contains(r.Id));
```

Comment: Used with Entity framework (and possibly LINQ-To-SQL), this will actually translate into "SELECT * FROM Table where Id in (1,2,3,4)", resulting in only one trip to the server.

Comment: @IgorZevaka - if it going to query the DB using EF, I'll prefer using SortedSet (which is sort of a superset of HashSet). It's also Unique, like HashSet, but Sorted too. I'll then Index my Db column on which I'm going to run the 'where' clause. That will be significantly faster in large data.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Contains() extension method:

```
list.Where(r => listofIds.Contains(r.Id))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the Join operator:

```
from r in list join i in listofIds on r.Id equals i select r
```

I'm not sure how this would be optimized over the Contains methods, but at least it gives the compiler a better idea of what you're trying to do.
It's also sematically closer to what you're trying to achieve.

Edit:
Extension method syntax for completeness (now that I've figured it out):

```
var results = listofIds.Join(list, i => i, r => r.Id, (i, r) => r);
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer (though using the extension method syntax, but that's simply personal preference). And yes, `join` is more optimized than `Contains`, as it constructs an in-memory hash table of the keys on both sides rather than doing a sequential search in `listOfIds` for every member of `list`.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Thanks, I just figured it out and deleted my comment, sorry.
For reference, I said I couldn't figure out the syntax and asked  for help